# How to find out last changelist number for a file

Tags: perforce

Is there a way we can find out the last changelist number for a file in Perforce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `p4 fstat`:

```
$ p4 fstat //depot/path/to/file
... depotFile //depot/path/to/file
... headAction edit
... headType ktext
... headTime 1348571116
... headRev 8
... headChange **496308**
... headModTime 1348571025
... 
$
```

If you mapped the file to a client-workspace, `p4 filelog -m 1` works similar.

Comment: And for specific revision. `p4 fstat //depot/path/to/file#revisionnumber`